# Hypernym for pluralise and singularise

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

To *pluralise* is to make plural, *dog* becomes *dogs*, conversely *singularise*.  What is the generic term for such actions?  The *number* of a verb is its singularity or plurality, so perhaps *numberise*?

Is there a word for the concept or process of pluralisation and singularisation?

Comment: *Quantify, quantification?* Give an example context where you might need such a term. *Not* as a name for a software entity, because that would be Off Topic.

Comment: "The student performed well in the test, but incorrectly ____ed the words _pence_, _activity_ and _cappuccino_."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referring to the [grammatical number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number):

> - In linguistics, grammatical number is a grammatical category of nouns, pronouns, and adjective and verb agreement that expresses count distinctions (such as "one", "two", or "three or more"). ***In many languages, including English, the number categories are singular and plural.*** Some languages also have a dual number or other arrangements.

As a verb I think you can use the expression ***to decline by number***.

[To decline](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/decline):

> - (In the grammar of Latin, Greek, and certain other languages) state the forms of (a noun, pronoun, or adjective) corresponding to cases, number, and gender.

(ODO)

Comment: "*Inflect* for number" would be more common now probably.

Comment: The phrase that is hypernymic for *pluralize* and *singularize* (pardon my American spelling, honestly come by) would be *change* or *alter* number.